# Alternatives to jQuery Mobile for mobile web apps? Zepto, XUI, what else?

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari

We use jQuery Mobile inside a PhoneGap app designed for iOS devices.

But it requires jQuery, which is very large.

The primary reason for using JQM is to help with page transitions, event management (e.g., bind, live, on), and touch events.

Are there lightweight alternatives to JQM that provide similar functionality? We know about Zepto and XUI.

We don't need the interface layer since we handle that on our own.

What are your experiences with these alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, we built our page transitions and tap event handling. Super simple, maybe two hours of work at most. This was the best alternative for us since all the other libraries offered a lot more than we needed. If all you need is basic page transitions and tap events, we recommend going this route as well. Otherwise, take a look at the options mentioned previously.

Answer (score 6):

I'd recommend Backbone and Zepto for an HTML-based app. Both are very lightweight, powerful, and easy to learn. You can use Zepto for CSS3-based animation/transitions and events, while Backbone helps you organize your code in a sane way. My experience with these tools has been primarily on a game targeting mobile devices written in Javascript. While the performance wasn't as good as native (as expected), it really wasn't too bad... for a more traditional, "business-y" app, I think Zepto/Backbone is perfectly viable.

Comment: thanks! does zepto handle page transitions as well or just element transitions? it's not clear from reading the docs.

Comment: Zepto will animate any HTML element. I think it's up to you to define what a "page" is in your app. For example, in the app I'm working on, a page is represented by a <div> that takes up the whole viewport. Other pages are hidden off-screen. When I want to display another page, I just tell the current page <div> to animate out and animate the new one in at the same time. It's similar to jQuery Mobile, but I have to specify the animations myself.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [JqMobi](http://jqmobi.com/testdrive/). Haven't used it and you will need to do the UI heavy lifting, plus it only runs on webkit, but since you are targeting iOS only, this should be ok.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using jqMobi for a couple of months, it gives you a lot of freedom on building almost anything and gives you the backbones without too many bounds, I seriously advice it!

Answer (score 1):

Following up butr0s - StanAngeloff on Github wrote Zoey based on Zepto.js over a year ago:  http://stanangeloff.github.com/zoey/

Though it hasn't been updated recently it is still an excellent wrapper for modern mobile browsers.  Very fast, handles page transitions (both single-page app and retrieving page content via AJAX).  It also has a sensible theme system similar to jQuery UI that you can extend.

Answer (score 0):

[EnyoJS Javascript Application Framework](http://enyojs.com/) seems also interesting